# SQL Query - To split the value into 2 column and group by same customer

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, I will like to split the value into 2 columns and group it by the same customer. Below is my current table:

I have tried the query:

> Select *
>
> ,Case when [Devices] = 'RF' THEN (Select [Lines] From table_name Else '0' )End As [RF]
>
> ,Case when [Devices] = 'Desktop' THEN (Select [Lines] From table_name Else '0') End As [Desktop]
>
> From table_name

But it gives me the error : This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Please advise if anything wrong with the query.
Thank you!!

| Customer | Lines | Devices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | RF |
| A | 4 | Desktop |

What I expected to see:

| Customer | RF | Desktop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

First problem: Don't use *, but provide the explicit column selection.

Second issue: You don't need to write sub queries in your `CASE WHEN` construct. The correct syntax of the query you've tried will be:

```
SELECT customer, 
CASE WHEN devices = 'RF' THEN lines ELSE 0 END AS RF,
CASE WHEN devices = 'Desktop' THEN lines ELSE 0 END AS Desktop
FROM table_name;
```

Third point: This will produce two rows: One row RF 3, Desktop 0 and one row RF 0, Desktop 4. But the expected outcome according to your description is one row only. To achieve this, you need to `SUM` your values and `GROUP BY` customer:

```
SELECT customer,
SUM(CASE WHEN devices = 'RF' THEN lines ELSE 0 END) AS RF,
SUM(CASE WHEN devices = 'Desktop' THEN lines ELSE 0 END) AS Desktop
FROM table_name
GROUP BY customer;
```

Especially when doing the second option, I recommend to check if the `ELSE` clause of your `CASE WHEN` is really required since this has no effect unless all values are NULL.
In these simple use cases, such queries will work correctly. If your table is more complex and you need to cover more different cases, you should have a look on functions like `PIVOT` instead of writing lots of `CASE WHEN` constructs.

A last note: All these queries assume that your column "lines" has a numeric data type. If this isn't the case, you need to convert it. The exact syntax how to do this depends on your DB.